# NGINX : Cache when X-Accel-Expires is set

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I have added a **X-Accel-Expires** header on my static contents as well as a **Last-Modified** header.
I would like to know whats the correct setting to cache those elements without caching anything else.

This is what I have at the moment but it doesn't cache anything :

```
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

sendfile        on;
client_max_body_size 2000m; 
keepalive_timeout  65;
tcp_nodelay        on;

gzip  on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/chain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.key;

proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m max_size=1G;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name domain;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_read_timeout 700;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To cache stuff, first you need to create a [proxy cache path](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path) within the `http` context, like this:

```
proxy_cache_path    /var/cache/nginx/site1    levels=1:2    keys_zone=site1:10m max_size=1G;
```

Then you can also optionally define the [proxy cache key](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key).  Any request that has the same cache key as a cached entry, will receive the cached reply, if there is one.  But default may already be good enough, so, that's entirely optional.

Then to enable the cache in a given context, just mention which cache should be used, like this:

```
proxy_cache    site1;
```

According to the description of the [proxy cache valid](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) directive, nginx already respects `X-Accel-Expires` and acts on it, so, you're basically done at this point.  Since you don't want to cache anything that doesn't include `X-Accel-Expires`, then you probably want to add a value of 0 as the default valid time (setting `X-Accel-Expires` within your content should overwrite this default value).

```
proxy_cache_valid    0m;
```

---

I shall presume that other than for the lack of any caching, your config file is otherwise valid, and your proxying itself already works.

Then, basically, all you need to do to fix your config is add the following to your `http`, `server` or `location` context:

```
proxy_cache    cache;
proxy_cache_valid    0m;
```

(Also, you might want to ensure that the cache path exists and has correct permissions, of course.)

---

Regarding the mentioned [habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/163847/) article/example, I don't think it's actually correct to be including `$http_if_modified_since` in the cache key, because you can potentially end up with a lot of multi-cached entries, effectively wasting your cache.

---

Also note that nginx likely doesn't proxy `X-Accel-Expires` header -- it only uses it internally, and IIRC may not serve this header forward.  To alter such behaviour, you have to explicitly ask for it to be proxied, too (in case you want to debug your content through nginx, and see how your app sets the header etc):

```
proxy_pass_header "X-Accel-Expires";
```

Comment: +1. If you use multiple levels of nginx, remember to set `proxy_pass_header "X-Accel-Expires";` at each level.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [good howto](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=fr&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://habrahabr.ru/post/163847/&act=url) about using of `X-Accel-Expires` header in nginx on Russian IT blog.
I think, it may be very useful in your case.

Comment: thank you, I use nginx as a proxy, I'm not using fastcgi. Do you think I can still use those settings ?

Comment: Sure, why not? This is very well described in [official nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid). Of course, depending on your project, you may have to experiment with some of the settings.

Comment: hangover, please consider expanding your answer beyond just 'here's a link'. If that ever link goes away your answer becomes totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that cache is defined but not enabled -- `proxy_cache cache;` is missing.

Comment: that will cache everything right ? I only want to cache when the X-Accel-Expires is specified